# How to create read only checkbox MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC. In the view there is check box, So I want to make it read only or user can't change it..

This is my view

```
     <tr id="pnHireSet">
                <td class="adminTitle">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsHireSet):
                </td>
                <td class="adminData">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsHireSet)

//This is check box. I want set is read only....
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsHireSet)
                </td>
            </tr>
```

How can I do it??
Thankx.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use `DisplayFor` instead of `EditorFor`.

If you need the value to be included in the form submission you could add a `HiddenFor` as well.

```
<td class="adminData">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsHireSet)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsHireSet)
</td>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to visualize the checkbox but turn of the control of the checkbox then simply you can try

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive, new { onclick = "return false" })
```

I don't prefer to use `disable=false` because if you need the checkbox value to the server then disable always send false either it views as checked in  state, that's the problem and difference.